# Subscriptions in Google Developer Console are stuck as "inactive"

Tags: in-app-billing, subscription, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I just publish my app for internal testing and all my subscriptions  [are blocked as "inactive"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0PzO.jpg). I cannot change the state. The app was published yesterday after 5 days of review, should I wait for the subscriptions to become active ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Has your app been reviewed? Is it published on Google Play, or still in review?

Comment: The app was on review for 5 days and was published yesterday into an internal test track, only available for testers.

Comment: Hey @youaremean, I am experiencing the same issue, did you figured out how to fix this ?

Comment: Hey @MuZak, I did! Really ashamed of myself though, because I was following along tutorials with screenshots of the old play console layout, I couldn't figure out where was the activate button, so here it is :
- You create your new subscription (before the activate button was here, not anymore)
- You click on your newly created subscription
- And at the bottom right corner of the page you have the "Activate" button
Hope it helps!

Comment: I did the exact same thing and was not able to see the button... I did found it by accident an felt ashamed too lol. Happy to see I am not the only one, thanks for the answer !